# Interference between string formatting and LaTeX functions

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, latex

Say I made a fit and obtained the parameter `a` (in reality there are more). Now I want to have a little piece of text inside a plot where the parameter and its unit is stated. The idea was to use the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=19389.2323
plt.figure()
plt.text(0.5,0.5, r'${0:.1f}\frac{kJ}{mol}$'.format(a/1000))
```

However the last line causes a `KeyError: 'kJ'` because the curly brackets are being interpreted by the `.format()` instead of being interpreted as being part of the LaTeX function.

I could of course hard-code the formatted version of `a` into the the code, but I was hoping someone had a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the curly brackets for the latex commands with another pair of curly brackets.

```
plt.text(0.5,0.5, r'${0:.1f}\frac{{kJ}}{{mol}}$'.format(a/1000))
```